RSA signature verification failing for smartcards
I am trying to sign a byte string using the c_sign function from pkcs and I am trying to verify it using RSA.verify() function in ASP.net, but for some reason its failing.
I am using 2048 bit RSA keys and I am trying to create a RSA SHA384 signature and I have tried using both CKM_RSA_PKCS and CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS and I have tried to verify them using c_verify and its giving success but when I tried to verify the output from .net its failing. Is it because the regular signature creation process is different from the PKCS c_sign process ?

My question has nothing to do with code or examples,  all I have asked is whether the RSA384 signing and verifying process in PKCS is different from the regular RSA signing and verification, it's a theoretical question.

If you think so... But note that if you provide the info, even if what you are saying is right, people might spot symptoms of little mistakes in how exactly you apply what should work. Parameters not matching your input, formatting non-conpatibilites....

Do you have an example that works with ASP.net?  If so can you recreate it with your c function and compare the output?  Is the ciphertext encoded the same way (binary vs base64 or whatever)?  Can the asp.net function tell you anything about why it fails? You describe an approach but there is no debug data so it limits what people can do to help you.  Also you have two parts and you don't know which one is at fault.

I am grateful for your efforts for trying to debug the code, but I will do that myself, I just want to know whether the signature generation process used in pkcs is different from the regular one, the reason why I wanna Know this is that, in this documentation I referred signatureprocess verification process it says something about BER encoding after hashing which I am not sure if it's done in regular RSA signature generation, so that's my question? Is it similar or not?

An RSA signature needs padding (usually PKCS#1 v1.5 or PSS), and unless your input is guaranteed to be short, a hash algorithm (like SHA384).
CKM_RSA_PKCS uses PKCS#1 v1.5 without hashing, while CKM_SHA384_RSA_PKCS adds SHA384. I could not find which RSA.verify function you mean in ASP.net, but you need to ensure that both sides (1) are hashing the input exactly once, and (2) are using the same padding scheme.
